# vim regexps from the perl's point of view: which special characters to escape with backslash

Tags: vim, escaping, vi

Imagine, we have to construct a regexp in vi/vim. Which special characters we have to escape with backslash?

By special characters I mean the following chars: {}|()-[]+*.^$?

Seems like we have to escape: {|()+?

And leave as is: }^$*.[]-

Thanks.

p.s. AFAIK, we have no '?' character in vi/vim but '=' instead which should be also escaped by backslash.

Comment: `\?` and `\=` do the same job. If you activate *very magic* mode, then `.?` will mean *one or no characters*.

Comment: Questions like these are welcome on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim:

> :help magic

Answer (score 3):

I think the Vim documentation on [magic characters](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) will give you a definitive list.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way, that will work regardless of vim's `magic` setting, is

```
let re = '\V' . escape(fixed_string, '\')
```

`\V` disables magic entirely from that point onward in the RE.  This means that anything not preceded by a single backslash (well, technically by an odd number of backslashes) is a normal character.  Since we escape any backslashes in the fixed string, there can be no magic characters contained in it.

Remember that with `\V` in effect, you have to backslash-prefix any RE meta-characters.  So if you're looking for a line that entirely consists of the fixed string, you would

```
let full_line_re = '\V\^' . escape(fixed_string, '\') . '\$'
```

Also keep in mind that vim's `ignorecase` and `smartcase` settings will affect RE behaviour.  The `\C` (case-sensitive) and `\c` (case-insensitive) switches work the same way as `\V`: they will override those settings for the part of any regexp which follows them.

Comment: One addition to this answer: you may even use the following pattern: `\v^.+(\VThis is not a meta character: .\v)+`. Here the usage is similar to `\Q`...`\E` in perl.

Comment: For overriding 'ignorecase' option you may also use `=~#` and `=~?` if you want pattern matching. In other case you have to supply `\c` or `\C`.